# Get ID of <td> to change inner HTML multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I problem is that I want to generate a random ID for each  in each row and then change the inner HTML of the specified  whenever a certain button is clicked.

I have tried adding the onload attribute for each row that is created to try to get the id with a function and then pass the id when the function is called but it didn't work

```
function add(){
    let taskInfo = `
<tr>
    <td>${generateId(4)}</td>
    <td>${productID}</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td class="taskid"id="${generateId(4)}">Idle</td>
    <td>
        <span class="action-start" id="${generateId(4)}"onclick="start(getId())">Start</span> 
        <span class="action-stop" >Stop</span>
    </td>
</tr>
`
let newTask = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
newTask.innerHTML = taskInfo;
console.log("New task added!")
}
```

This is the function that adds the rows to the table ^

[image]

So what I am expecting to get is that when the users click start the status  changes to a certain status, individually in each row

Comment: You'll need to use data attributes (ie `data-id`); element ids _must_ be _unique_.

Comment: Are you using any framework or just vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: What framework are you using? .... You could have a global variable (that stores the last ID value) and initialize it to zero e.g var tableRowID = 0; Then in your "add" function say something like id="${tableRowID}" and at the end of the function increment it as follows: tableRowID++ (so that it will always be unique)..it would help us more if you showed us your "start" function and your "generateId" function also...